# Jenkins and xstream - WARNING: Failed to resolve class

Tags: java, jenkins, xstream

im writing a class that read wsdl with XStream on Jenkins.
I use XStream 1.4.7, everything is working, but when i start server i get a lot of Warnings.

[LOG](http://79.96.4.173/mmorawski/log.txt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED.
 Jenkins is missing plugins - org.jenkinsci.plugins.envinject.EnvInjectPluginAction
org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.DownstreamBuildViewAction 
...
and xstream is trying to read xml in this plugins.